# Subtracting date datatype - number data type

Tags: apex, date

Can anybody solve my problem regarding date?

```
Variable = Date__c - number__c;
```

I am not sure about my result,

for example : `(____/____/_________(Result in Date) = ____/____/_________(Date) - 12(number))`

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to do. Do you want to add/subtract days from a date? Have you tried the [addDays method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_addDays)?

Comment: thanks for reply. i want like this 25/8/2015 - 14 = DATE

Comment: Is 11/8/2015 the result you are expecting?

Comment: Yes. Exactly i am expecting this date in result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [addDays](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_addDays) method on Date can be used to give you the result you want:

```
Date myDate = Date.newInstance(2015, 8, 25);
Date newDate = mydate.addDays(-14);
```

You can also just simply add/subtract an integer value from the date variable as shown below

```
Date myDate = Date.newInstance(2015, 8, 25);
Date newDate = myDate - 14;
```

Comment: Date myDate = Date.newInstance(Date__c); this is not working....

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Is that the actual line of code you are using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are curious about what methods apex has that operate on the Date class, here is a link that might help you:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm

Comment: Please do more than posting a URL. Explain the essential parts that will answer the question and user the link as reference. That way we make sure the answer is provided here, and not on a website that may dissapear.

Answer (score 0):

I solved out from the following code.....

LeadTime = Week_Beginning__c(Date Data Type) - Lead_Time_Days__c.intValue() (Number Data Type)

Thanks..

Comment: Was this how you've solved your question or is it more detail about the question itself ? It's not entirely clear to us, you had already marked the question as answered.

Comment: So you Mean i have to add my answer  in my own question..Right ?